# Add a Right-Click Menu Item in Visual Studio using C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in, visual-studio-addins

How to write an add-in that allows me to right click on the files hierachy tree to do something that will display something?

This is exactly what I want (please see the 2nd part of the video):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb614548.aspx

Unfortunately, it is in VB; I need a C# version.

Comment: (the C# approach will be pretty much identical to the VB, once you have the VS SDK installed, no?)

Comment: SDK installed already. But how is SDK useful? My VS already got the Extensibility section, and I don't need the extra stuff I think...

Answer (score 1):

Writing VisualStudio plugins is a pretty terse task. What you are searching for has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210323/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-add-a-visual-studio-2008-context-menu-item).

You also might want to check out [DXCore](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/) from Devexpress. It provides nice abstractions above the VS API that might help you getting things done faster.

Comment: I just need sth simple like the one shown in the video above. But I want it in C#. The 1st link u provide is all in visual basic. The 2nd link is not what I want.